# Perturbation of roots in Wilkinson's polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra

I am studying numerical analysis.  When I read the online [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial)  I found on this paragraph:

- Suppose that we perturb a polynomial $p(x) = Π (x−α_j)$ with roots
  $α_j$ by adding a small multiple $t·c(x)$ of a polynomial $c(x)$, and
  ask how this affects the roots $α_j$. To first order, the change in
  the roots will be controlled by the derivative
  $\frac{d\alpha_j}{dt}=-\frac{c(\alpha_j)}{p'(\alpha_j)},p'(\alpha_j)$
  is the derivative of $p(x)$.

How did they get the formula for the change of the root=$-\frac{c(\alpha_j)}{p'(\alpha_j)}$?  This same definition also appears in Trefethen's numerical linear algebra book, but there's no explanation there either.

I know this may be a dumb question but thanks for helping me out!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $F(x, t) = p(x) + tc(x)$. Then
$$
  F(\alpha_j, 0) = 0 \, , \quad F_x(\alpha_j, 0) = p'(\alpha_j) \ne 0 \, .
$$
It follows from the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)
that there is a differentiable function $\alpha$, defined in a neighbourhood
of $t = 0$, with $\alpha(0) = \alpha_j$, such that the solutions
of $F(x, t) = 0$ in a neighbourhood  of $(\alpha_j, 0)$ are given by $x = \alpha(t)$.

$\alpha(t)$ is the zero of the perturbed polynomial $p(x) + tc(x)$,
and the derivative can be determined by differentiating
$$
 p(\alpha(t)) + tc(\alpha(t)) = 0
$$
with respect to $t$:
$$
  p'(\alpha(t)) \alpha'(t) + c(\alpha(t))  + t c'(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)= 0
$$
Now set $t = 0$:
$$
  p'(\alpha_j) \alpha'(0) + c(\alpha_j)  = 0
$$

Comment: @starry1990: You are welcome!

Comment: I do not understand a neighbourhood of $(\alpha,0)$. Isn't $\alpha$ a function? What does a neighbourhood of $(\alpha,0)$ mean?

Comment: Didn't you mean a neighbourhood of $(\alpha_{j},0)$ ?

Comment: @mali1234: You are completely right, that was a silly typo. Thanks for telling me!